# ReSharper Current Line Highlight getting changing back to default

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm using Son of Obsidian color scheme and I've noticed every so often ReSharper Current Line Highlight goes back to the default color.  To fix it all I have to do is go into Fonts and Colors and press ok and it goes back to normal.  However it's really annoying when it happens and was wondering if anyone else is having this issue?  Not sure if it's a VS or ReSharper bug.

Comment: Am I the only one having this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem and would like to know solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, I think I have narrowed it down to when I upgrade Resharper. Best way is to export your settings and then reimport them after upgrading.

Another thing that I have noticed is if you have two instances of VS open when you close the last instance it will override any changes you made in the previous instance.